# POST PHP variable is not being printed on the pdf with PDFcrowd

Tags: php, pdf

I've started to use PDFcrowd and I'm having the following problem. At the top of my page I'm calling these two variables.

```
$fullname1 = 'Franky';
$fullname2 = (empty($_POST['fullname'])) ? '' : trim($_POST['fullname']);
```

Then I'm echoing both variables in the html code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="https://mydomain/convert-with-pdfcrowd.php" method="post"><button type="submit">Convert</button></form>
    </div>
    <h1>Hello <?php echo $fullname1 ?></h1>
    <h1>Hello <?php echo $fullname2 ?></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As expected, I've got the result below:

**Hello Franky**

**Hello Domino**

So they both worked. The problem is when I then convert the page with PDFcrowd, only the variable $fullname1 gets printed to the PDF and the result looks as follow:

**Hello Franky**

**Hello**

So what happened to the variable $fullname2, why the name Domino is not being printed on the pdf? I was thinking to convert it to a string e.g. `$str2 = (string)$fullname2;` but it didn't work either.

Comment: We need to see the relevant code to know what is happening (convert-with-pdfcrowd.php) but in the form, you are not passing the original $_POST when submitting the form, so that is probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Of course yes I'm not passing the original $_POST. Looking into this. Thanks.